# How can I deselect a loop cut layer of vertices?

Tags: vertices, loop

I have tried a few ways to deselect a layer of vertices, however I am a little stuck.

I can deselect 1 vertice (Shift+select vertice).
I can deselect multiple vertices (Ctrl+Shift+LMB > drag lasso over preferred vertices).
I can select a face, however this doesn’t allow for loop cuts to have their inner layers selected.

I’ve noticed this is for selecting layers (in loop cuts):
CTRL+Alt+LMB on vertical edge, for horizontal layer
and
CTRL+Alt+LMB on horizontal edge, for vertical layer.

**I need to deselect layers.**
Therefore, these are the steps I've figured out:
CTRL+Alt+Shift+LMB on vertical edge, for horizontal layer
and
CTRL+Alt+Shift+LMB on horizontal edge, for vertical layer.

However, the challenge now is that these steps don’t deselect one layer, but rather two or three layers. How can I deselect one layer?

Any suggestions please?
[image: Image of object and its loop cut layers I need to deselect]

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of layers you're referring to. Are you trying to deselect edge loops?

Comment: I added an image of the loop cuts and the layers I need to individually select. (not sure if this is called edge loops?)

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to _select_  the loops, and then Ctrl-I invert the selection, but @BluTackMan's answer should work with default keymapping.

Comment: Tried the invert, but original 1 layer selected becomes 2 layers deselected.  For some reason, 1 layer is not deselecting?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do this?

[image]

If so, then just press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, and <kbd>SHIFT+ALT+LMB</kbd> to deselect the loop that you want, and it is the same in the edge and face modes.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes, but for 1 layer rather than 2.  I added an image to my original post for better clarity.  Shift+Alt+LMB does nothing.  Shift +Alt+RMB moves the cursor to the mouse pointer.

Comment: @user1416486       Alt-Shift-LMB  should _toggle_ the selection state of a loop, and therefore work.. not for you?

Comment: Nothing.  I have changed the default key mapping RMB to LMB.

Comment: You are only deselecting one loop, if you want to do it in face mode, then it will only deselect one loop of faces.

Comment: According to the tutorial, deselecting a layer of vertices should work.  I tried faces and this worked for all but the last rack layer, where I deselected vertices.